# Не выводятся вариации товара, если атрибут указан кириллицей woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, кириллица

Если я указываю атрибут товара(в данном случае 'Цвет') для вариации на русском языке, то у меня функция `wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options()` выводит вот такую кашу в атрибутах и id

```
<select 
id="%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82" class="" 
name="attribute_%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82" 
data-attribute_name="attribute_%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82" 
data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="">Выбрать опцию</option>
</select>
```

ecли я указываю название атрибута(Color) на англ., то у меня выводит следующее:

```
<select 
id="color" 
class="" 
name="attribute_color" data- 
attribute_name="attribute_color" 
data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="">Выбрать опцию</option>
  <option value="Красный" class="attached enabled">Красный</option>
  <option value="Черный" class="attached enabled">Черный</option>
</select>
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы функция срабатывала верно с атрибутом указаном в админ-панели с помощью кириллицы?

Comment: url decode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Cпасибо! Помогло)

Comment: Напишите ответ, как именно решили проблему, где что и на что заменили =) может кому то пригодится, а может еще и плюсов наберете.